# Wordpress в записи вывести отдельно текст до тега more, разделить контент

Tags: wordpress

Видел мануалы и примеры, как выводить текст до тега `<!--more-->.`
Но не хватает знаний, чтобы сделать вывод на живой записи.

Помогите пожалуйста правильно сделать вывод в этом коде:

```
<?php get_header()?>
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
  <div id="main" class="col-sm-12 clearfix" role="main">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article" itemscope>
        <header>
            <header>
              <div class="page-catheader cat-catheader">
                <h1>
                  <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h1>
              </div>
        </header>            
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">
              <header>
              <div class="single-page">
                    <div class="meta nopadding">
                       &nbsp;<span class="sprite amp cat-icon-small">
                            <?php $category = get_the_category(); ?>
                            <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
               </div> 
               <div class="single-img-container">
                   <div class="single-img">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured' ); ?>
                   </div>
            <div class="single-nfo">
                       <div class="single-nfo-block">

                            <div class="single-nfo-text">ТУТ ТЕКСТ ДО ТЕГА MORE</div>


                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>

              </header>
      <!-- end article header -->
      <section class="post_content clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
      </section>
      <!-- end article section -->
    </article>
    <!-- end article -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

  </div>
  <!-- end #main -->
</div>
<!-- end #content -->
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Я не соображу, как разделить контент на две части, выводя текст до more в нужном блоке, а остальной как обычно.

Comment: Почитайте https://wp-kama.ru/function/the_excerpt. И по вёрстке, что-то у вас количество открывающих тегов header кажется не совпадает с закрывающими.

Comment: Как просто в любом месте вывести часть контента , в том числе и до more, я знаю. Но сделать это рамках одного поста не могу. Нужно же "разорвать" <?php the_content(); ?>, а не просто вывести кусок текста, получится дубль.

Comment: Я потому вам и написал, что вам нужно выводить не the_content(), а the_excerpt() до тега more.

Comment: В нужном блоке вывели текст до more. А дальше как остальной тогда вывести? Без more уже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл!

```
<?php $more=0; the_content('',false); ?>

Остальной текст после more:

<?php $more=1; the_content('',true); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Меняете в вашем коде `<div class="single-nfo-text">ТУТ ТЕКСТ ДО ТЕГА MORE</div>` на

```
 <div class="single-nfo-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
```

а ниже выводите собственно ссылку "Читать полностью..." как-нибудь так:

```
<div class="read_more">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Читать полностью...</a>
</div>
```

То есть, ссылкой на полный материал должна служить функция the_permalink(). При этом у отдельных страниц (page) должен иметься собственный шаблон page.php, а у записей из рубрик - шаблон single.php. Отображения статей целиком редактируется уже в них.

Comment: Мне и нужно разделить текст на странице с полным материалом. Конечная страница. Там разделить текст на два блока.

Comment: Блин, только тут сообразил, ЧТО вам нужно. Самый простой способ - куску, что был до тега more - присвоить отдельный класс и через css придать ему особое оформление и, конечно, вывести всё это через the__content().